# Spontaneity and nature of attack of fluorine gas on aluminum

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-table

What is the nature of the reaction of attack of fluorine gas on aluminium metal? Is it spontaneous in nature?

I have studied reactions of halogens on aluminium, but it had no information about fluorine's attack, and I would like to know about this reaction.

> Aluminium has a tenacious oxide layer so the reaction of gaseous fluorine with aluminium metal is firstly the reaction of fluorine with aluminium oxide.

So finally $\ce{F2}$ will react with $\ce{Al2O3}$? Also will $\ce{F2}$ react with fresh $\ce{Al}$ metal surface.

Comment: I have edited the question and made it more readable, getting a good idea on English sentences and writing would be great since it was very hard to read before. Your title should reflect the question that you want to ask. Hope you get an answer for this question and enjoy learning :D.

Comment: Aluminium has a tenacious oxide layer so the reaction of gaseous fluorine with aluminium metal is firstly the reaction of fluorine with aluminium oxide.

Comment: Use `$\ce{}` for chemical compounds

Comment: What do you mean by "spontaneous"? If you mean "exergonic", I recommend to use that term.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First and foremost! **Do not do this reaction unless you are properly trained and have the appropriate safety equipment. Fluorine is one of the most dangerous substances out there, and one of the presumed products, $\ce{OF2}$, is also terrifying.**

If you can calculate the free energy change for a reaction, you will know whether it is spontaneous. To do this, you need to have more information than you currently provide. We need to know the products of the reaction in order to write a balanced chemical equation. Then we can look up appropriate thermodynamic values for each substance in the reaction in order to calculate the free energy change. Below is what I presume to be the balanced equation for the reaction of fluorine with aluminum oxide:

$$\ce{Al2O3 + 6F2 -> 2AlF3 + 3OF2}$$

Using the [NIST Chemistry Webbook](https://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/), we can look up the enthalpies of formation and standard entropies of each substance so that we may calculate the enthalpy and entropy changes.

$$\begin{array}{l|c|c|c|c|c|c}
& \ce{Al2O3} & \ce{F2} & \ce{AlF3} & \ce{OF2}  \\ \hline
\Delta_f H^\circ\ \mathrm{(kJ/mol)} & -1675.7 & 0 & -1510.4 & 24.52 \\
S^\circ\ \mathrm{(J/K)} & 50.92 & 202.8 & 66.5 & 247.46 \\
\end{array}$$

We can use these data to calculate the free energy change of the reaction:

$$\Delta_r G^\circ = \Delta_r H^\circ - T\Delta_rS^\circ$$

If the free energy change is negative at that temperature, the reaction is spontaneous.

Comment: But does it go kinetically?  I can see it with aluminum _hydroxide_, but the anhydrous oxide may be hard to attack unless heated.

Comment: Quoting Housecroft and Sharpe, second edition, section 12.4 "Reactions of Al with halogens at room temperature ... give the Al (III) halides ..."

Comment: A person without proper training does not have access to fluorine gas. ;)

Comment: @Karl - I would like to believe that to be true everywhere in the world, but I cannot guarantee it.

Comment: @Karl Couldn't you extract it from fluoridated water with electrolysis?

Comment: @nick012000 Per https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4547570/ the target concentration for drinking water fluoridation is 0.7 mg/L ($1.84 \times 10^{-5}$ mol/L), so I don't think that's practical.  (I'm not sure whether the article means 0.7 mg of $\ce{F-}$ or 0.7 mg of $\ce{NaF}$; if it's $\ce{NaF}$, the molarity is even lower.)

Comment: @zwol Looking up the LD50 of fluorine gas, it looks like 100ppm is enough for a lethal dose (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK220011/), and according to Wolfram Alpha, 1 ppm of air is equivalent to 1 mg, so you'd probably be able to produce enough for a lethal dose by electrolysing 150L (approximately one bath tub) of fluoridated water at those concentrations. Obviously, this isn't something anyone should actually do.

Comment: @nick012000 Electrolysis of a "bathtub" of fluorinated water seems to me unlikely to produce fluorine given fluorine will spontaneously react violently with water to produce oxygen (or ozone if there is excess fluorine which there surely won't be here) and HF.

Comment: What's your reasoning for the reaction you wrote down rather than $\ce{2Al2O3 + 6F2 -> 4 AlF3 + 3O2}$?

Comment: @Jan Oxygen reacts with fluorine? Because _everything_ reacts - if it hasn't already reacted - with fluorine?

Comment: @Karl Ah, good point. Fluorine is probably in excess after all. That's what I get for morning comments ^^'

Comment: Oxygen does not react with fluorine unless you introduce something like BF3 into the mix, or with an electrical discharge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorine#Reactivity I have no reference to support me, but I would expect Jan's reaction to be right